# How do i get the effect of a UISwitch as the accessory for a UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a working UITableView filled with some options for my app, and i want to add UISwitches to them just like the Settings app, how do i do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own custom accessory view.  When handling `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, just create a switch in the row cell like this:

```
UISwitch* turboSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 84.0, 27.0)];
[turboSwitch setOn:[engine.turbo boolValue]];
cell.accessoryView = turboSwitch;
cell.textLabel.text = @"Turbo";
```

Don't forget to connect the target action to your controller.